# Best way to split/duplicate an Xcode Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

What's the best way to split or duplicate an Xcode project?

Here's my situation.  I have a fairly large workspace with a number of projects in it.  One of the projects has grown a little too large and I would like to split it in the least disruptive way possible.  My idea was to duplicate the project so it appears twice in the workspace.  Then I can rename one of the projects and delete things that I don't need from each project.  Is there a clean way to do this in Xcode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best way was to make a copy of the folder I want to duplicate it, rename the project, then add the project to the workspace.  Then I can delete things as needed.